# qsqltablemodel incompatible data types

Tags: qt, ssms, qsqltablemodel

I have a simple form with button and some line edits and listview.
In listview users can select items and in line edits edit their parameters.

```
int row = listView->selectionModel()->currentIndex().row();
QString text = lineEdit->text();
sqlTableModel->setData(sqlTableModel->index(row,3),title,Qt::EditRole);
sqlTableModel->submitAll(); //when this line is execeute i get an error
```

error:

```
QODBCResult::exec: Unable to execute statement: "[Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]The data types varchar(max) and ntext are incompatible in the equal to operator. [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared."
```

Comment: If you have the possibility to change the data table you should probably do that. Convert the data type of columns from NTEXT to NVARCHAR(MAX).

Comment: @user2672165
Datatype of the column in database is varchar,
I have tried to change it to NTEXT and to NVARCHAR but it is not working.
It always shows me the same error.

Comment: I have exactlly the same problem with PyQt. I thing this is because there are incompatible types in WHERE clause (Update/Insert...) Is this problem related with the ODBC/QODBC driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that this question is 2 years old, but when trying to do this in other application, I found a solution. So this might be useful for anyone who will google it.

> The data types **varchar(max)** and **ntext** are incompatible

In the database I have used data type **ntext**, but Qt uses **varchar**. So the solution is in the first comment in my question, which I didn't understand before 2 years. The only thing to do, is to change the data type in database to **varchar**.